# How to append an html tag containing md-checkbox and md-icon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-material

I am working with angular material and angular js and i am trying to append a new html div when a function is called from the view.

This is my view:

```
    <div id = "main_row" ng-click="defCtrl.submit()">
    </div>
```

This is what i am trying to do inside the controller:

```
    self.submit = function()
    {
    $('#main_row').append("<div>
    <md-card layout='row'>
      <md-checkbox flex='80'>                
          Hello 
      </md-checkbox>
     <md-button class='md-icon-button' 
     aria-label='close'> 
       <md-icon  style='fill:red;height: 15px' md-svg-icon=
         'notes/static/img/cancel30.svg'>
       </md-icon>
     </md-button></md-card></div>");
    };
```

The md-card part is getting displayed properly. But the md-checkbox and md-icon fails to load. Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally advised not to manipulate the dom in a controller, but it can be done. This should be close to what you want

```
<div id = "main_row" ng-click="submit(evt)"></div>

angular.module('whatever').controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile){
  $scope.submit = function(evt){
    angular.element(evt.currentTarget).append($compile(
      "<div>
        <md-card layout='row'>
          <md-checkbox flex='80'>                
            Hello 
        </md-checkbox>
        <md-button class='md-icon-button' aria-label='close'> 
        <md-icon style='fill:red;height: 15px' md-svg-icon='notes/static/img/cancel30.svg'></md-icon>
      </md-button></md-card></div>"
    )($scope));
  };
}]);
```

Comment: But md-card is getting displayed properly

Comment: Is it functioning though? It also has css classes that target md-card the tag, which would work fine without being compiled. The functionality wouldn't work and neither would any of the directives that target any of the compiled html

Comment: Yeah ..it comes like a card but no checkbox and svg image? Do you know any other way to make it work?

Comment: Updated answer with a way that should work or be close to working

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather recommend you to use the ng-repeat directive instead of a jQuery solution.

Why meddle in the DOM with jQuery, when you can natively do it within angular? There are special md- tags involved after all.

Like:

```
<div id = "main_row" ng-click="addHelloCard()">
</div>

<div>
  <md-card layout="row" ng-repeat="card in helloCards">

    <md-checkbox flex="80">
      Hello {{card}}
    </md-checkbox>

    <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="close"> 
      <md-icon  style="fill:red;height: 15px" md-svg-icon="notes/static/img/cancel30.svg">
      </md-icon>
    </md-button>

  </md-card>
</div>
```

While in the controller:

```
$scope.helloCards=[];
$scope.addHelloCard = function() {
  $scope.helloCards.push("Perhaps an object containing information...");
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain why you recommend this solution over another.

Comment: Thanks..i implemented it using ng-repeat. Initially i was trying to diplay using client side code..bt later i understood fetching from database and using ng-repeat is much easier..Thanks again

Comment: avk, I just edited my answear regarding your comment, thx! I'm happy it helped you Jithu!